# File Upload with Progress bar for asp.net - Without flash

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

I'm looking for a technique in order to upload files and show the progress.
Both [componentart](http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/upload/features/core_features/webform1.aspx) and [componentone](http://demo.componentone.com/ASPNET/ControlExplorer/C1Upload/CustomProgress.aspx#) use an ajax calls to a file with axd extension.
I want to build my server control to works like these. ( I don't want to use these components )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice free javascript library you can use to do it here: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.

Right now, they only have examples of how to implement this in Perl, PHP, and Java, but I'm sure you could get the idea and implement it in C# or VB (whatever you're using).